# Python: How does one use variables defined in main(), and/or use a lists with two classes without errors?

Tags: python, class, compiler-errors, tkinter, python-2.6

Objective: I have tried using variables in main() and creating a random list of messages in my code, which have partially worked, but are still coming up with multiple errors that I don't know how to fix.

Question: Could someone fix my code so the errors are gone, and the program at least works as intended?

In the main() section of my code I define several buttons, which I think messes up the GUI of the timer section of my program after the first break timer. The objective box is supposed to reappear in the window, but it doesn't. This also may have something to do with the .destroy() command. How would I fix it so the label and entry widget reappear in the initial window?

How this question is different: I am aware that there is a large number of questions regarding some of these common errors, but my code is unique, and thus requires a different post.

Code: (This should be all formatted correctly, pull it into your favorite IDE and run it to debug)

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import random


class PopUp():
    def __init__(self):
        top = self.top = Toplevel()
        self.inp = StringVar()
        self.nth = 0
        top.geometry("240x135+25+300")
        Label(top, text="Suggestion:").pack(side=TOP)
        self.message()
        Label(top, textvariable=self.inp)

    def message(self):
        self.inp.set(random.choice(self.mess))

    mess = ['Nice Job! Go take a walk outside!',
            'Nice Job! Wiggle your toes, and get back on it!',
            'Nice Job! Get up and walk around!',
            'Nice Job! Go get a drink of water!',
            'Good Work! Go take a walk outside!',
            'Good Work! Wiggle your toes, and get back on it!',
            'Good Work! Get up and walk around!',
            'Good Work! Go get a drink of water!']


class Timer(Frame):
    def __init__(self, stb, st, rb, qb, parent=None, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()
        self.inp = None
        self.stb = stb
        self.st = st
        self.rb = rb
        self.qb = qb
        self.timer1 = 9
        self.checkTimer1 = 1
        self.timer1Run = 0
        self.tempObj = 0
        self.entdat = StringVar()
        self.timestr = StringVar()
        self.makeTimer()
        self.makeWidgets()

   def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Timer")

    def makeWidgets(self):
        minutes = int(self.timer1/60)
        seconds = int(self.timer1 - minutes*60.0)
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds))
        self.ol = Label(text="Objective:")
        self.ol.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2, side=TOP)
        self.ew = Entry(textvariable=self.entdat)
        self.ew.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2, side=TOP)
        self.b = Button(text="OK", command=self.clicked)
        self.b.pack(side=TOP)


    def makeTimer(self):
        self.l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self.l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)

    def makeButtons(self, st, stb, rb, qb):
        self.destroy()

    def updateTime(self):
        self.elapsed = time.time() - self.startTime
        self.curtim1 = self.timer1 - self.elapsed
        if self.curtim1 <= 0:
            self.stop()
            self.checkValue()

        else:
            minutes = int(self.curtim1/60)
            seconds = int(self.curtim1 - minutes*60.0)
            self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds))
            self.timer = self.after(1, self.updateTime)

    def checkValue(self):
        if self.checkTimer1 == 1:
            self.distroy_Widget()
            self.timer1 = 3
            self.checkTimer1 -= 1
            self.start()

        else:
            self.dat.destroy()
            self.makeWidgets()
            self.timer1 = 9
            self.checkTimer1 += 1
            pu = PopUp()
            pu.message()
            self.start()

    def start(self):
        if not self.timer1Run:
            self.startTime = time.time()
            self.updateTime()
            self.timer1Run = 1

    def stop(self):
         if self.timer1Run:
             self.after_cancel(self.timer)
             self.timer1Run = 0
             self.timer1 = self.curtim1

    def reset(self):
        self.timer1 = 900
        minutes = int(self.timer1/60)
        seconds = int(self.timer1 - minutes*60.0)

        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds))

    def clicked(self):
        self.distroy_Widget()
        self.dat = Label(self, textvariable=self.entdat)
        self.dat.pack(side=TOP)

    def distroy_Widget(self):
        self.ew.destroy()
        self.ol.destroy()
        self.b.destroy()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("240x235+25+50")
    tm = Timer(root, stb, sb, rb, qb)
    tm.pack(side=TOP)

    sb = Button(root, text='Start', command=tm.start).pack(side=LEFT)
    stb = Button(root, text='Pause', command=tm.stop).pack(side=LEFT)
    rb = Button(root, text='Reset', command=tm.reset).pack(side=LEFT)
    qb = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)

    mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is there a reason that those buttons aren't in your "Timer" class with the other UI elements?  If so, is there a reason that you are trying to pass them to the Timer constructor before they even exist?

Comment: The commands they use: (tm.start, stop, reset and root.quit) can only be accessed through main() I think. Unless you can show me a counterexample. A friend suggested moving them up to Timer, but when it didn't work gave up on it, and said, try to keep them where they are.

Comment: Looks to me like the variables are scoped in main, try making them all `global`.

Comment: Change "tm" to "self" for code in a method.  Every method has a pointer to the object that it is acting on, passed as the "self" argument.  There's no need for a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but the code indenting in your question isn't quite right. However—ignoring that relatively minor issue and the fact that the following modified version of it doesn't address all your questions—you may still find it useful because it does get rid of the errors about using variables in`main()`by making them all attributes of the`Timer`class, the only place they're referenced, and initializing them in its`__init__()` method—essentialy what @Mike Housky suggested in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872410/python-how-does-one-use-variables-defined-in-main-and-or-use-a-lists-with-tw#comment44147355_27872410). I also renamed a few things to be more consistent.

This should get the GUI running well enough to allow you can deal with the remaining problems yourself.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import random

class PopUp():
    def __init__(self):
        top = self.top = Toplevel()
        self.inp = StringVar()
        self.nth = 0
        top.geometry("240x135+25+300")
        Label(top, text="Suggestion:").pack(side=TOP)
        self.message()
        Label(top, textvariable=self.inp)

    def message(self):
        self.inp.set(random.choice(self.mess))

    mess = ['Nice Job! Go take a walk outside!',
            'Nice Job! Wiggle your toes, and get back on it!',
            'Nice Job! Get up and walk around!',
            'Nice Job! Go get a drink of water!',
            'Good Work! Go take a walk outside!',
            'Good Work! Wiggle your toes, and get back on it!',
            'Good Work! Get up and walk around!',
            'Good Work! Go get a drink of water!']

class Timer(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")
        self.initUI(parent)
        self.inp = None
        self.timer1 = 9
        self.checkTimer1 = 1
        self.timer1Run = 0
        self.tempObj = 0
        self.entdat = StringVar()
        self.timestr = StringVar()
        self.makeTimer()
        self.makeWidgets()

    def initUI(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Timer")
        self.sb = Button(self.parent, text='Start',
                         command=self.start).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.stb = Button(self.parent, text='Pause',
                          command=self.stop).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.rb = Button(self.parent, text='Reset',
                         command=self.reset).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.qb = Button(self.parent, text='Quit',
                         command=parent.quit).pack(side=LEFT)

    def makeWidgets(self):
        minutes = int(self.timer1/60)
        seconds = int(self.timer1 - minutes*60.0)
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds))
        self.ol = Label(text="Objective:")
        self.ol.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2, side=TOP)
        self.ew = Entry(textvariable=self.entdat)
        self.ew.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2, side=TOP)
        self.b = Button(text="OK", command=self.clicked)
        self.b.pack(side=TOP)

    def makeTimer(self):
        self.l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self.l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)

    def updateTime(self):
        self.elapsed = time.time() - self.startTime
        self.curtim1 = self.timer1 - self.elapsed
        if self.curtim1 <= 0:
            self.stop()
            self.checkValue()
        else:
            minutes = int(self.curtim1/60)
            seconds = int(self.curtim1 - minutes*60.0)
            self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds))
            self.timer = self.after(1, self.updateTime)

    def checkValue(self):
        if self.checkTimer1 == 1:
            self.destroyWidgets()
            self.timer1 = 3
            self.checkTimer1 -= 1
            self.start()
        else:
            self.dat.destroy()
            self.makeWidgets()
            self.timer1 = 9
            self.checkTimer1 += 1
            pu = PopUp()
            pu.message()
            self.start()

    def start(self):
        if not self.timer1Run:
            self.startTime = time.time()
            self.updateTime()
            self.timer1Run = 1

    def stop(self):
         if self.timer1Run:
             self.after_cancel(self.timer)
             self.timer1Run = 0
             self.timer1 = self.curtim1

    def reset(self):
        self.timer1 = 900
        minutes = int(self.timer1/60)
        seconds = int(self.timer1 - minutes*60.0)
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds))

    def clicked(self):
        self.destroyWidgets()
        self.dat = Label(self, textvariable=self.entdat)
        self.dat.pack(side=TOP)

    def destroyWidgets(self):
        self.ew.destroy()
        self.ol.destroy()
        self.b.destroy()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("240x235+25+50")
    tm = Timer(root)
    tm.pack(side=TOP)
    mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my minor indentation error. I just knew I messed up somewhere. :)

Comment: And besides that, thanks for helping me! I'm somewhat of a new comer to the programming scene, and this site has been very encouraging to me.

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW, I've found fixing problems -- my own or others -- to be a great excuse to either learn something new or refine my understanding of stuff I think I already know or have only heard about.